# I want to read the same file several times in Java

Tags: java, buffer, bufferedreader, filereader

I want to read a file several times in the same execution when the file is modified. I did these piece of code but when I read the file on the second time it says that there aren't more lines.

The file is a .csv like this one:

```
"v1";"v2";"v3";"v4";"v5"
"33455";"15.06.2018 20:48:44";555;555;43
"234455";"15.06.2018 20:49:10";555;555;42
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException, IOException 
{
    String csvFile = "file.csv";

    readCSVFile(csvFile);

    Date lastFileModifiedData = getFileLastModifiedData(csvFile);

    while(true)
    {        
        Date fileModifiedData = getFileLastModifiedData(csvFile);
        if (!lastFileModifiedData.equals(fileModifiedData))
        {
            readCSVFile(csvFile);
            lastFileModifiedData=fileModifiedData;
        }

    }
}

public static void readCSVFile(String csvFile) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    String line;
    String cvsSplitBy = ";";

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(csvFile);

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr)) {
        if (scan.hasNextLine())line = scan.nextLine(); 
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
        {      
            line = scan.nextLine();
            String[] details = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            details[0] = details[0].replace("\"","");
            details[1] = details[1].replace("\"","");


            System.out.println("VarName=" + details[0] + " , TimeString=" + details[1] + " , VarValue=" + details[2] + " , Validity=" + details[3] + " , Time_ms=" + details[4]);;

        }
    }
    fr.close();

}
```

Comment: the same file multiple files? what do you mean?

Comment: I did a mistake, I edited it. I want to say read the same file multiple times in the same execution

Comment: are you sure you changed file and SAVED your changes before the second run? Do you enter to if (!lastFileModifiedData.equals(fileModifiedData)) condition?

Comment: yes! When the file is modified and saved I enter to if (!lastFileModifiedData.equals(fileModifiedData)) condition and I enter to readCSVFile where when I call scan.hasNextLine() it says that there are no line